# How do I resize the canvas of a image layer in After Effects?

Tags: after-effects, adjustment-layers

I'm using **After Effects CC 2017**. I've imported a PNG image with transparency, then I added a simple **CC Light Wipe** effect:

[image]

The problem is that the range of the lights produced by this effect are limited to the image size, so it produces an annonying thingy. Is there a way to resize the canvas of the layer of the image or another way to solve this (avoiding the need to resize the image canvas using external programs like **Photoshop**)?.

I really tried to find out the answer researching in Google before asking here but I only found questions about resizing the entire compossition in the compossition settings...

Comment: May I suggest that you spend a few hours going through some introductory video tutorials: http://aefreemart.com/the-mega-list-adobe-after-effects-tutorials-for-beginners/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an adjustment layer on top (right-click in empty area of the layer names. Go to New menu) Apply the effect to that.

Answer (score 1):

And because there's always two ways of doing anything in After Effects:

- precompose the layer to which you want to apply the effect.
- In the pre-compose dialogue choose "leave all attributes…".
- Resize the new composition to the size you need.
- Then in the original composition apply the effect to the pre-comp.